How to Reproduce Data Loss Due to Unflushed Kernel Buffers?
I recently encountered an issue in my Linux development environment. I wrote a function to export results to an Excel file, triggered by a button click. After the function executes, it flushes the user-space buffer and shows a "success" dialog. However, if the user removes a USB drive too quickly, the file isn't saved to the drive, even though the dialog appears.
I understand this happens because the data is still in the kernel buffer and hasn't been written to the hardware. I resolved the issue using fsync.
Now, I want to test and reproduce this problem systematically. What would be the best way to do this?
I tried various approaches, such as executing a command to disconnect the USB drive immediately after the write function completed, as well as other actions. I even tried doing it manually, but I couldn’t reproduce the issue.
I know this issue is related to the kernel buffer, but I can’t find a simple example to reproduce it effectively, which is quite frustrating.

If your USB flash drive uses VFAT, Linux's or Ubuntu's default for removable FAT devices probably includes the flush mount option which will "try to flush to disk more early than normal."  So small writes that can be sent to the flash drive in moments (not writing multiple megabytes) may get sent very soon after you close a file, instead of waiting a few seconds before even starting write-back.

I solved it. I can do the operation in the virtual machine, execute it and stop it without fsync.
Here's how you can change the test:
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void sync_file_with_fsync(const std::filesystem::path& dest_path) {
    int fd = open(dest_path.c_str(), O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        std::cerr << "无法打开文件进行 fsync: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (fsync(fd) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "fsync 失败: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "fsync 成功，数据已写入磁盘。" << std::endl;
    }
    close(fd);
}

int main(){
    std::filesystem::path source_path = "/home/mq-b/test/test_fsync/1MB_file.dat";
    std::filesystem::path dest_path = "/media/mq-b/MQ-B/1MB_file.dat";
    std::filesystem::copy_file(source_path, dest_path, std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);

    sync_file_with_fsync(dest_path);

    std::clog << dest_path << " 文件复制完成,大小：" << std::filesystem::file_size(dest_path) << " Byte" << std::endl;
}

If you annotate the call to sync_file_with_fsync, then run the program, pause the VM after printing out the file size, and then check the USB key, you will see that there is no file. The dest_path does not actually have a file, but it gets its size because the filesystem of the operating system does the same thing as if the copy were completed, but we are actually accessing the kernel buffer.
